# Reconfigure networking as fresh install

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04

I am user of the [create_ap](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap) program and Ubuntu 18.04, and works great, but testing with the --no-virt option I have broken the wifi, now the WiFi menu is empty and can't find any wifi connection. Any idea on how to revert that without a full reinstall?

I have used dpkg to reconfigure /etc/network packages without success.